# Magento 2 : Get value and name of cookie in phtml

Tags: magento2, cookie

I have a cookie like this:
[image]

How can i get value and name of this in phtml file?

Any help? Thank in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get cookie in a Block and hence cannot use it in phtml file as a PHP variable.

If you want to use the cookies in Javascript you can use the following

```
<script>
  require(["jquery"], function($){
    var cookie = $.cookie("example");
  })
</script>
```